# How can I use the Ubuntu Server from my USB stick?

Tags: software-installation, downloads

I'm new into Ubuntu and I have some questions. The questions may look stupid but I want to be on a safe side.

1. I'm based in Germany and I want to download Ubuntu server for self education, is it still free to download here in Germany?
2. I want to use the Ubuntu server software from my USB stick without installing it to my laptop, is this possible?
3. And where I can find useful literature for self education?

Comment: Yes, sure it's free. You can start a live system, don't know about Ubuntu Server though. Did you search for any literature? I think it's easy to find. Start with [official ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/) or german community [ubuntuusers.de](https://ubuntuusers.de/).

Comment: Since you are going to use it on a laptop (not a server), you may want to start with the Ubuntu desktop version to get yourself familiar with how Ubuntu works (unless you specifically need the server version for some reason).

Comment: Ubuntu Server is available on *live* media for some later releases; but not all *supported* releases (you didn't mention the release you want). Loads of documentation is available; some good & some bad, so I'd stick with official generally to start with. As you get more skilled, you'll be able to detect what's good & what's not & go elsewhere; but it can lead you wrong if bad documentation is used.  Example of official will be https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-server#1-overview

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi it's not odd at all to use a laptop as a "makeshift" server, so this may very well be the intended usecase.

Comment: Canonical has a very extensive [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs) -  this is a good starting point for many questions.

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to reflect the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, you can download an iso file with Ubuntu Server, and it is free. Check that the download is good with a checksum, `sha256sum`.
- When downloaded you can clone it to a USB drive so that you can boot from it.
- Then you *can install* Ubuntu Server into a USB drive (best is an SSD connected via a USB adapter).

  Normally you would install it into an internal drive, but it is also possible to install Ubuntu Server into an external drive.

  - If you can unplug the internal drive of the computer, it should be straight-forward to use the generally recommended ['live server'](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.3/). (After the installation you can plug the internal drive back into the laptop.)
  - Otherwise I would recommend that you download the ['ubuntu-20.04.1-legacy-server-amd64.iso'](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-legacy-server/releases/20.04/release/), which has a more flexible installer. It is easiest to avoid touching to internal drive, if you install in legacy mode (alias CSM alias BIOS mode). Avoid UEFI mode if possible.
- You can find a lot of information about Ubuntu Server and Linux in general via the internet search engines. You can start with the following links, and then ask *new* specific questions if there is something that you cannot find.

  - https://ubuntu.com/server/docs
  - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Servers